# Calling custom UIView draw function alongside animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation

I have a custom `UIView`. How can I create a animation function that calls a custom draw function `drawCanvas(fraction:CGFloat)` instead of animating CALayer properties by key.

I'd like to animate a view prepared in **Paintcode** with the “fraction” variable exposed. It shows an updated image for values ranging from 0 (start) to 1 (end).

I also like to use different timings/easings, so having a NSTimer calling the draw function feels too rigid.

Comment: You must use an own layer class for that, add an animatable property and redraw when the property changes during animation. Another option would be to use a CADisplayLink to draw manually along with every screen update. The former is described really well in this article: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animating-custom-layer-properties/ (although objc it's very similar in Swift)